# What type does the MyCustomClass.class.getName return?

Tags: apex, class

```
public class MyCustomClass {

    public static void main() {
        MyCustomClass myClass = new MyCustomClass();

        String myClassName = myClass.class.getName(); // myClassName equals 'MyCustomClass'
    }
}
```

What type does the `myClass.class` return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_type.htm) in the Apex developer guide

> The ***class*** property returns the ***System.Type*** of the type it is called
> on. It is exposed on all Apex built-in types including primitive data
> types and collections, sObject types, and user-defined classes.

And, `getName()` is a method of `System.Type` class.